# Getting stock information in opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, stock

To do easier checks of our stock informations, I would like to show the stock in the order view, and on the proforma.

Till now I was just trying to add it in the order view, but I didn't had luck with it. I don't really have experience in php, or I don't really have any coding skills.

So what I added in `order_info.tpl` is

```
`<td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['stock'] ?></td>`
```

but not working.
I was searching for the solution, but I found details only about showing it on category page, and I guess on the admin page is something different. 
I might add something in one of the PHP files? 
Thank you!

Update: I need stock quantity. 
[Here a picture, right side is where I want to show the stock quantity remaining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUVhX.png)

Comment: you are need quantity stock or stock status ? please ask clearly here. or upload with screenshot as well

Comment: Where you want to show it in Admin order view, or customer order information view?

Comment: On the Admin order view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Follow this Two step as well

> Step : 1  admin\controller\sale\order.php

**A :** Find this

```
public function info() {
```

after Add below code

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

**B:** Find this

```
$data['products'][] = array(
```

after Add below code

```
'stock'            => $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']),
```

> Step : 2 admin\view\template\sale\order_info.tpl

**A :** Find this

```
<td class="text-right"><?php echo $column_total; ?></td>
```

after Add below code

```
<td class="text-right"><?php echo 'Stock-Quantity'; ?></td>
```

**B :** Find this

```
<td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
```

after Add below code

```
<td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['stock']['quantity']; ?></td>
```

**C :** Find this

```
<td colspan="4" class="text-right"><?php echo $total['title']; ?></td>
```

Replace this code

```
<td colspan="5" class="text-right"><?php echo $total['title']; ?></td>
```

> You can see below screenshot as well

[image]

i hope this articles very helpful for you. if you are appreciate with my code. please give me up-vote and review for this answer.

Comment: I tried it, but now it shows the ordered quantity from the product. (As I said, I need the stock quantity in order_info.tpl, to show at the end of every row the stock of the product ordered)

Comment: I edited the question, please check it with the screenshot.

Comment: you can send email to  bhoraniyamujahid@gmail.com right now or send your whatsapp contact number. i will solve your issue

Comment: you need to product remaining quantity right ? in order info page ???

Comment: And what about the order_invoice.tpl? I tried the same, but not working. I get Notice: Undefined index: stock in .....
And actually is there a way to show the customer's phone number there too?

Comment: send me your project URL ?

Comment: Nevermind, I found other solution :) Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: please upvote my answer @Szél Ádám. this is very important for me. Thanks in advanced