# Getting stock information in opencart 3.x

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I want to implement a task similar to the one here [Getting stock information in opencart 2.3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819914/getting-stock-information-in-opencart-2-3-0-2), but my problem is that when deleting a product, the information about the warehouse will disappear. I want to enter the data into the table order_product, but I still don’t understand how. Help me please.

I can't figure out how to write information about the rest of the goods to the database. I don't understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... You want to save product`s stock information in order_product table?

So first you must to add custom field in oc_order_product

```
ALTER TABLE `oc_order_product` ADD `stock_status` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `reward`;
```

Then in *catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php* in **$order_data['products'][] = array(** You must add key - stock_status

```
'stock' => $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id'])['stock_status'],
```

So we modified our controller in customer side, and now our data receive the stock_status.

After receive products data from customer side, we must save in oc_order_table

Open path - *catalog/model/checkout/order.php* and edit addOrder function... After `reward = '" . (int)$product['reward'] . "'` in products loop add after comma:

```
stock_status = '" . $this->db->escape(product['stock_status']) . "'
```

I write an example, how to save data from customer side about product stock data.